# Finding the identifiers of plugins installed from Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: eclipse

As stated, I need to locate the identifiers of the plugins I have installed via the Eclipse Marketplace.

For plugins installed via `Help -> Install New Software` it is easy

[image]

EDIT: Originally this question was asked in the context of how to Add Eclipse Marketplace plugins to the Install New Software tool because I knew how to find the identifiers from there, but the real question was simply how to find the identifiers in any way so I have rephrased the entire question.

Comment: why do not open Eclipse Marketplace directly from the eclipse menu?

Comment: Because I need to find the resource IDs by clicking “more” (below Details) -> General Information -> Identifier.

Comment: Did you try to add the marketplace in "Available Software Sites"?

Comment: The marketplace isn't a software update site so you can't do this.

Comment: Then how will I ever add plugins to an Oomph Product setup, which requires the identifiers to do so?

Comment: You can review the identifier number after installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Benja Garrido pointed out, you can review the identifier number after installing from the Marketplace.

[image]